# Different URL format in blazor app between prod and dev environments

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am working with a server side blazor app, .Net8.  I have been having trouble with the base tag in the App.razor file.

I have the href set as in the Microsoft docs as "/Project/" which works fine for prod but when I am in dev and debugging etc. this format doesn't work and I have to set it too "/".

I have just wrapped a prod version and a dev version of the base tag in with an if statement and used an environment variable, but I just wanted to know if this is standard practice, or if I should be doing any of this at all?

I tried using the environment helper tags with include/exclude but these do not work.